# Is there a way to auto close a spark/jupyter session

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, jupyter

I work as a hadoop admin and as a developer. We are having a cluster with CDH distribution. There are multiple teams who use the cluster and users are not proactively killing spark shell sessions or the jupyter notebook sessions.

Instead of asking the users what i was thinking is to have a idle timeout or a auto close configuration which can be set in the code

I have searched in google but didn't find a proper solution. If anyone has used such kind of configuration sharing that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Idle timeout for Jupyter kernel sessions can be configured via Kernel Manager’s `cull_idle_timeout` (Check: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).

If you are using Spark via Livy, `livy.server.session.timeout` garbage collects  inactive Livy sessions. This can be specified in `conf/livy.conf` under Livy. Default value is one hour.

Comment: Thanks Naman for your reply. 
Actually we start our jupyter sessions from putty. 

We have added few export commands in .bashrc. Whenever we want to start any jupyter session we just open CLI(putty) and run either pyspark or pyspark2 which returns a URL. Copy pasting this in a browser starts jupyter session. 

I actually tried adding the one which you suggested into the bashrc it says that it is not a jupyter command